# How to load jstree child nodes using ajax?

Tags: tree, nodes, jstree

I need to now about the jstree. I am using it in one of my project. I need help regarding the loading of the child nodes using ajax.

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270239/creating-dynamic-jstree-using-alternative-json-format-stored-in-array/26299310#26299310

Comment: make a normal jquery ajax call and whenever you make an ajax call with new url, assign the response to arrayCollection and refresh the tree this way: $('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = arrayCollection;                 $('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#treeloaddiv').jstree({
        'core' : {
          'data' : {
            "url" : "/jstreedemo/JSTreeDemoServlet",
            "type":"post",
            "dataType" : "json",
            "data" : function (node) {

                    return { "id" : node.id };
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

this is code for jstree v3 in the servlet in my case need to create a json object and
set the childrens property as true then each child is loaded using ajax.
the json format is as follows

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
jsonobj.put("text","Root node");
jsonobj.put("children",true);
```

hope it helps i was also stuck at this point for many days.