# jsTree how to change ajax url and reload data

Tags: jstree

```
    $('#jstree_demo_div2').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                "url": "tree.ashx?id=" + _id,
                "dataType": "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
            }
        },
        "checkbox": {
            'visible': true,
            'keep_selected_style': false, 
        },
        "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"]
    });
```

I need to change the url (or the variable `_id` will change) and then refresh data.
But there seems to have a cache problem.

I monitored the HTTP request, the request param `_id` didn't change.

I've tried

```
'core': {
                'data': {
                    "url": "tree.ashx?id=" + _id,
                    "cache":false, //←←←←
                    "dataType": "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
                }
            },
```

and it didn't work.

BTW, my jsTree.js version is 3.0.8.

Comment: And beform I use `$('#jstree_demo_div2').jstree('refresh');` to refrase the data, the param `_id` has been changed.

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270239/creating-dynamic-jstree-using-alternative-json-format-stored-in-array/26299310#26299310 you can store the ajax returned json in arrayCollection variable

Comment: make a normal jquery ajax call and whenever you make an ajax call with new url, assign the response to arrayCollection and refresh the tree this way:             $('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = arrayCollection; $('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();

Comment: @Quick_Silver Thanks for the advice. But there seems to be some problems: 1)The refresh operation collapses the whole tree  2)The 'status' filed (to check the checkbox) doesn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am using the following code to test your use case. It's refreshing the jstree without collapsing the whole tree.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSTree</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/themes/default/style.css" />
        <script src="dist/libs/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/jstree.js"></script>
        <script>
            var arrayCollection;
            $(function() {
                arrayCollection = [
                    {"id": "animal", "parent": "#", "text": "Animals"},
                    {"id": "device", "parent": "#", "text": "Devices"},
                    {"id": "dog", "parent": "animal", "text": "Dogs"},
                    {"id": "lion", "parent": "animal", "text": "Lions"},
                    {"id": "mobile", "parent": "device", "text": "Mobile Phones"},
                    {"id": "lappy", "parent": "device", "text": "Laptops"},
                    {"id": "daburman", "parent": "dog", "text": "Dabur Man", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "dalmatian", "parent": "dog", "text": "Dalmatian", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "african", "parent": "lion", "text": "African Lion", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "indian", "parent": "lion", "text": "Indian Lion", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "apple", "parent": "mobile", "text": "Apple IPhone 6", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "samsung", "parent": "mobile", "text": "Samsung Note II", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "lenevo", "parent": "lappy", "text": "Lenevo", "icon": "/"},
                    {"id": "hp", "parent": "lappy", "text": "HP", "icon": "/"}
                ];
                $('#jstree').jstree({
                    'core': {
                        'data': arrayCollection
                    },
                    "checkbox": {
                        'visible': true,
                        'keep_selected_style': false
                    },
                    "plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"]
                });
            });
            function resfreshJSTree() {
                $('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = arrayCollection;
                $('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();
            }
            function addNokia() {
                var nokia = {"id": "nokia", "parent": "mobile", "text": "Nokia Lumia", "icon": "/"};
                arrayCollection.push(nokia);
                resfreshJSTree();
            }
            function deleteDalmatian() {
                arrayCollection = arrayCollection
                        .filter(function(el) {
                            return el.id !== "dalmatian";
                        });
                resfreshJSTree();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="addNokia()" value="Add Nokia"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="deleteDalmatian()" value="Delete Dalmatian"/>
        <div id="jstree"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- **Note:**
- After opening the above page in a browser, Open all the nodes and child nodes of the jstree.
- Click on Add Nokia button.
- It will add Nokia Lumia node to Mobile Phones node without collapsing
  the tree to root node.
- Similarly click on Delete Dalmaitian button.
- And it will delete Dalmatian node from Dogs node and refreshes the
  tree to display the new structure without collapsing to root node.

Comment: The code that answers the question is just the content of the `resfreshJSTree` function. `$('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = 'put/the/url/here.json';` and `$('#jstree').jstree(true).refresh();`

Comment: What worked for me:  
`$('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data = { 'url': 'put/the/url/here.json' };`

Comment: $('#jstree').jstree(true).settings.core.data.url = 'put/the/url/here.json';

Comment: Thank you Quick_Silver . It save my time.

Comment: Thank you. This is a perfect answer