# Jstree JSON object

Tags: java, json, jstree

In order to populate Jstree with nodes I want to create a JSON object looks like bellow,

```
[
    {
        "data": "Basics",
        "state": "closed",
        "children": [
            {
                "data": "login",
                "state": "closed",
                "children": [
                    "login",
                    {
                        "data": "results",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "attr": {
                            "id": "node-123"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "data": "Basics",
                "state": "closed",
                "children": [
                    "login",
                    "something",
                    {
                        "data": "results",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "attr": {
                            "id": "node-456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": "All",
        "state": "closed",
        "children": [
            {
                "data": "AddCustomer",
                "state": "closed",
                "children": [
                    "login",
                    "Add",
                    {
                        "data": "results",
                        "state": "closed",
                        "attr": {
                            "id": "node-789"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I am stuck with creating model object related to this JSON object. Is there any common model object that I can generate above JSON object?

Comment: like http://json-schema.org ?

Comment: which version of jstree you are using v3 or v1 because data format is different in both

Comment: hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731955/jstree-how-to-change-ajax-url-and-reload-data/26967099#26967099

Comment: or you may try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270239/creating-dynamic-jstree-using-alternative-json-format-stored-in-array/26299310#26299310

Comment: thnks it was really help helpful