# jsTree not showing up checkbox even adding required plugin

Tags: jstree

I am using the [JS tree sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270239/creating-dynamic-jstree-using-alternative-json-format-stored-in-array) link to display a hierarchy using JSTree. 
I am able to display the tree as in the below screenshot

[image]

So far so good. To this am adding checkboxes instead of bullets and used the below plugins object provided by official [jstree site](https://www.jstree.com/docs/config/) .

```
$('#jsTreeContainer').jstree({
            plugins: ["checkbox"],
            core: {
                'data': arrayCollection,
                "themes": {
                    "icons": false
                }
            },
            "checkbox": {
                "three_state": false,
                "whole_node": true,
                "keep_selected_style": false,
                "tie_selection": true

            },
        });
```

But still I am seeing the same output( am not getting checkboxes) and also the tree is expanding only when double clicked on node.

Can someone give me ideas on how to display checkboxes and also how to expand a node by just clicking it once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrongly pointed required js/css files which caused this issue.
I am now seeing checkboxes properly and also nodes are getting expanded when clicked once.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I reviewed my js and css files paths. Following are the files which should be referred:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<link href="~/Contents/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```